# Lets Encrypt with CNAME (cross domain) on k8s

Tags: lets-encrypt

Like the gitbook provide a [custom domain](https://docs.gitbook.com/hosting/custom-domains) I've to design
a service and user can register their custom domain. For example, I've a service
**hosting.example.com** and user can register any domain based on this service. In the case
I wish user JUST edit the CNAME, for example **sub1.example.net** CNAME TO **hosting.example.com**.

My service already process the virtual host and can provide service normally on HTTP. Now I have to provide HTTPS with lets encrypt. I've survey the [acem.sh](https://github.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh/wiki/DNS-alias-mode) but HAVE TO extra CNAME **_acme-challenge.sub1.example.net**. I want to reduct this step and keep user just edit DNS one and only one CNAME record.

Since my service is based on the K8S environment and HTTP-01 challenge is not suitable on this case.

[UPDATE]
Since I've using the wildcard CA, the DNS 01 seems the only possible method.

Comment: Why don't you use an HTTP challenge? You can certainly do this on k8s. It would be rather useless if k8s couldn't handle HTTP...

Comment: @MichaelHampton I've a two environment production and staging which staging only access with whitelist IP address. I'm not sure HTTP 01 / cert-manager is workable or not. I'll check it right now

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally I solve my question.

First, the DNS-01 will force verify the *_acme-challenge* DNS prefix so my original question is not possible. In my scenario I've provide two issuer: DNS-01 and HTTP-01, and one for my wildcard CA purpose and one for the dynamic CNAME purpose.

Based on the same namespace there are two issuer: letsencrypt-dns01 and letsencrypt-http01. When I need the wildcard CA I create a certificate and issuerRef point to the letsencrypt-dns01.

And more, when create the certificate based on the [python](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python), the service (deployment) need to add extra service account with related permission.